# #define SQR(x) x*x. Unexpected Answer

Tags: c++, macros

Why this macro gives output 144, instead of 121?

```
#include<iostream>
#define SQR(x) x*x

int main()
{
    int p=10;
    std::cout<<SQR(++p);
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to learn C++, why not an inline function? As you can see, macros can cause problems with evaluation...

Comment: See Bjarne Stroustrups [FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro). It explains what's wrong with using macros and gives exactly the same example that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach of squaring with this macro has two problems:

First, for the argument `++p`, the increment operation is performed *twice*. That's certainly not intended. (As a general rule of thumb, just don't do several things in "one line". Separate them into more statements.). It doesn't even stop at incrementing twice: The order of these increments isn't defined, so there is no guaranteed outcome of this operation!

Second, even if you don't have `++p` as the argument, there is still a bug in your macro! Consider the input `1 + 1`. Expected output is `4`. `1+1` has no side-effect, so it should be fine, shouldn't it? No, because `SQR(1 + 1)` translates to `1 + 1 * 1 + 1` which evaluates to `3`.

To at least partially fix this macro, use parentheses:

```
#define SQR(x) (x) * (x)
```

Altogether, you should simply replace it by a function (to add type-safety!)

```
int sqr(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

You can think of making it a template

```
template <typename Type>
Type sqr(Type x)
{
   return x * x; // will only work on types for which there is the * operator.
}
```

and you may add a `constexpr` (C++11), which is useful if you ever plan on using a square in a template:

```
constexpr int sqr(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a pitfall of preprocessor macros. The problem is that the expression `++p` is used *twice*, because the preprocessor simply replaces the macro "call" with the body pretty much verbatim.

So what the compiler sees after the macro expansion is

```
std::cout<<++p*++p;
```

---

Depending on the macro, you can also get problems with operator precedence if you are not careful with placing parentheses where needed.

Take for example a macro such as

```
// Macro to shift `a` by `b` bits
#define SHIFT(a, b)  a << b

...

std::cout << SHIFT(1, 4);
```

This would result in the code

```
std::cout << 1 << 4;
```

which may *not* be what was wanted or expected.

---

If you want to avoid this, then use inline functions instead:

```
inline int sqr(const int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

This has two things going for it: The first is that the expression `++p` will only be evaluated *once*. The other thing is that now you can't pass anything other than `int` values to the function. With the preprocessor macro you could "call" it like `SQR("A")` and the preprocessor would not care while you instead get (sometimes) cryptical errors from the compiler.

Also, being marked `inline`, the compiler may skip the actual function call completely and put the (correct) `x*x` directly in the place of the call, thereby making it as "optimized" as the macro expansion.

Comment: You can pass `'A'` or any other numeric value to this function (assuming you intended a parameter type of `int`); worse, it will silently give an unexpected result if you passed a floating-point value. A template might be more suitable, especially as a replacement for the macro.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Of course you are right, but I think templates may be a little bit over the head of the OP at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are using undefined behaviour. When the macro is expanded, your code turns into this:

```
std::cout<<++p*++p;
```

using increment/decrement operators on the same variable multiple times in the same statement is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? How/why is this undefined? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because SQR(++p) expands to ++p*++p, which has undefined behavior in C/C++. In this case it incremented p twice before evaluating the multiplication. But you can't rely on that. It might be 121 (or even 42) with a different C/C++ compiler.

Comment: And, more importantly, it has undefined behaviour in C++ (about which this question is) as well.

Comment: @Angew: yes, of course. Thank you. I've changed C to C/C++ in my text.